# How to override a vendor Process class?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony6

I'm trying to understand how to override a __construct in Process class. By default, construct only accepts an array as first parameter:

```
public function __construct(array $command, string $cwd = null, array $env = null, mixed $input = null, ?float $timeout = 60)
```

But I need for it to accepty strings aswell, which means something like this

```
public function __construct(array|string $command, string $cwd = null, array $env = null, mixed $input = null, ?float $timeout = 60)
```

Only overriding is accepted for solution tho, nothing else.
I need this because of Behat tests, since when I run them, I get error "Process::__construct(): Argument #1 ($command) must be of type array, string given"

Answer (score -1):

As one option, you can change the incoming arguments by creating your own class extends the Process component:

```
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;

class CustomProcess extends Process
{

    public function __construct(array|string $command, string $cwd = null, array $env = null, $input = null, ?float $timeout = 60)
    {
        if(is_string($command)){
            $command = [$command]; // do something with a string
        }
        parent::__construct($command, $cwd, $env, $input, $timeout);
    }
}
```

Then create an instance of your class in your controller like so:

```
$command = new CustomProcess('you command');
$command->run();
```

Comment: I'm getting error 'Cannot autowire service: argument "$command" of method "Process:__construct()" is type-hinted "array", you should configure it's value explicitly."

Comment: Have you created a service? If yes, then you don't need to. Just create a folder src\Process and add your class there.